# How to make unordinary shape for TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I need to create a specific shape for the Tab. It should look like this

[image]

Is is possible to create it via shape? Or just to use it as an image?

I also saw that some people use this way when they have to create very specialized tabs: they simply create all variants of all tabs in photoshop, selected and unselected, (for example,tab1_selected, tab1_unselected,...), but they do not create images for each tab, but literary they create the whole TabWidget image (for example, image with tab1 selected, and other tabs unselected) and then they load the appropriate image when certain tab is selected.

- Is this the right way to do it? This way you can create really cool tabs with thick bottom dividers, etc.
- How should I load the whole TabWidget background in this way? The usual way via `background` attribute or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code and the `MyClass` in code is the **ClassName** in which the code is written:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            MyClass.setTabColor(tabHost);
        }
    });

public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg); //unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_selected); // selected
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on the first part of question - creating the specific shape?

Comment: Just make the image as you required and the background but transparency will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although the transparency can be cheated if I set the color the same as TabWidget bg color. :)